# Как узнать, откуда пользователь пришёл на сайт?

Tags: php

Есть ли универсальный способ узнать, откуда пришёл пользователь - из поисковых систем, из социальной сети, со стороннего сайта или совершил прямой заход?

Comment: Яндекс метрика, Google Analitics?

Comment: @Дмитрий они как-то передают информацию при входе на сайт? Если нужно делать запросы к API, то мне это не подходит.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` пробовали?

Comment: @KostaB. сейчас создал тестовый php файл с `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` и разместил на него ссылку в одной из переписок ВКонтакте. Перешёл на страницу, а там пусто. Значит, переходы из ВКонтакте будут учитываться как прямые заходы. И в самой документации php сказано, что "доверять этому заголовку нельзя". http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Это не 100% вариант, во всех будут фолс позитивы. Учитывая, всевозможные `adBlock`'и и прочие варианты защиты от рекламной слежки.

Comment: Хостер обычно предлагает свою полную статистику (webstat в ispmanager). Её и парсить для себя. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно использвать ссылку с get параметром пример `href="mysite?param=1"` и на нашем сайте делать проверку:

```
if ($_GET['param']) {
    // мы пришли от туда где зазместили ссылку
}
```